# How do I implement lazy module loading in Perl?

Tags: perl, lazy-loading

How can I implement lazy module loading in Perl?

I've seen similar things in python and implementation is somewhat simpler, but in Perl I think this would be a bit harder.

Comment: Why do you think it would be harder in Perl?

Comment: I guess it was mostly a gut feeling.  Not really anything substantial.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Load module when you want

If you need to load whole module at runtime you use [`require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html). But for importing you'll require additional code. Here is example:

```
## this function is almost the same 
## as "use My::Module qw( :something  )"
sub load_big_module_at_runtime {
    ## load module in runtime
    require My::Module;
    ## do import explicty if you need it
    My::Module->import( ':something' );
}
```

### Load module when its functions are used

You can also [use `autouse`](http://perldoc.perl.org/autouse.html) to load module only when its function is used. For example:

```
## will load module when you call O_EXCL()
use autouse Fcntl => qw( O_EXCL() );
```

### Load function only when it's used

There is also [`SelfLoader`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SelfLoader) module, which allows you to load single functions only when you need it. Take a look at [`AutoLoader`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?AutoLoader) module which doing nearly the same thing.

I also recommend to read coresponding recipes from [Perl Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565922433).

Comment: The second part of your answer is very interesting.  I had no idea that module existed.  Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at `SelfLoader` module too.

Comment: Has anybody used `if` to achieve that?

Comment: `if` is usefull if you need to decide: load or not load module.